# How can I blow-up a smooth projective surface with certain conditions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $K$ a canonical divisor on $X$.

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X(nK))$ (for $n$ large).

Q: How can we blow-up $X$ to obtain $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ so that the subsheaves of $\mathcal{O}_Y(n\pi ^*K)$ generated by the sections in $V$ and $W$ are invertible?

It seems that $\pi$ is blow-up along ideal sheaves $I,J$ associated to $V,W$. $\underline{\text{Right}}$?

If it's true, then $\underline{\text{what are} \ I \ \text{and} \ J}$?

and let $I':=\pi^{-1}I\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y$. Then $I'$ is invertible. $\underline{\text{Is} \ I' \ \text{subsheaf of} \ \mathcal{O}_Y(n\pi ^*K)}$?

Comment: I think it's a general statement that if you have a torsion free sheaf $\mathcal F$ on a variety $X$, then you can find a blow up $\pi: Y \to X$ so that the torsion-free quotient of $\pi^*\mathcal F$ is locally free.   In the case that $\mathcal F$ has generic rank one, it is just an ideal sheaf, and you blow-up along the zero locus of the ideal sheaf.   In the rank $> 1$ case, you could first of all twist by some $\mathcal O(n)$ to assume that there are plenty of global sections, and then put $\mathcal F$ into a s.e.s. with lower rank kernel and cokernel, and proceed by induction.

Comment: P.S.  There will be many references for this fact.  Probably it's somewhere in EGA, but is also surely in the stacks project, which might be easier to google.  I would try googling some expressions like "torsion free sheaf becomes locally free after blow up".